# Erase UIImage by lightness?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uigraphicscontext, heightmap

I have a height map (a grayscale image, with black as the lowest and white as the highest areas), and I'm trying to isolate everything above or below a certain threshold.  My goal is to be able to take any height map, and return a new UIImage where everything below a certain height (i.e. darker than a given color) is copied, but anything above (i.e. lighter) is simply transparent.

[image]

Now I'm very new to this, so if there's a better way to go about this I'd love to hear it, but my first instinct is to create a new UIImage with the same frame, and then draw into it based on the lightness of a given area in the original.  Something like...

```
-(UIImage*)mapIsolatedFromThreshold:(CGFloat)threshold showAbove:(BOOL)above;
```

Thus, the `threshold` variable could be `0.7` or `0.2` or whatever, and then you could set `above` to `YES` if you want everything higher (i.e. lighter) than the threshold, or `NO` if you want everything lower (i.e. darker).

The thing is, I've never done image processing or drawing before, so I don't know how to set up that method.  I have a vague sense that it will involve `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` and such, but I haven't been able to find any questions or tutorials that use it based on the lightness of another image.

How would I go about making a method like that?  Or is there some pre-existing system for handling height maps in iOS, that makes this all a lot easier than I'm treating it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of hunting around, I was able to piece together this method.  And in case anyone else needed to do something similar, here it is.  I still don't fully understand what it's doing, step by step, but the end result is what I wanted.

```
-(UIImage*)imageWithLumaMaskFromDark:(CGFloat)lumaFloor toLight:(CGFloat)lumaCeil forImage:(UIImage*)image {
    CGImageRef rawImageRef = image.CGImage;

    const CGFloat colorMasking[6] = {lumaFloor, lumaCeil, lumaFloor, lumaCeil, lumaFloor, lumaCeil};

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
    CGImageRef maskedImageRef = CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(rawImageRef, colorMasking);
    {
        //if in iphone
        CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, image.size.height);
        CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, -1.0);
    }

    CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height), maskedImageRef);
    UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    CGImageRelease(maskedImageRef);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return result;
}
```

The `lumaFloor` and `lumaCeil` inputs take values between 0 and 255, and everything outside that range becomes fully transparent.